# Book with a Troll girl, treeclub, with talking sun and castrated husband deserted father carcass?

Tags: story-identification, books

Anyone know of this book, I thought it was called *The Last Simolean* but it's like unexisted now?

There's like an Amazon lady that bonks her head and like ends up a troll after being haunted by a talking sun, and a troll queen who uses her father's corpse.

Comment: "Unexisted"? Try to add details: is it an old book, or new? Do you remember the cover? When did you read it? Do you remember anything else about the plot?

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&ORDERBY=title_title&USE_3=title_title&USE_2=title_title&CONJUNCTION_1=AND&TERM_1=the+last&START=3000&CONJUNCTION_2=AND&OPERATOR_3=exact&OPERATOR_2=exact&OPERATOR_1=starts_with&TYPE=Title - One of these?

Comment: I didnt see it in the covers section of that site either. I am pretty sure the title is correct. But when I search I am google bombed by The Sims Game content from Maxis. I think the publisher was something with a B like behemeth or a bat

Comment: Is there a bantam version of the book below.  I remember the title was like the Last Somelon.

Comment: Do you know what a transient book is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a long shot, but I wonder if this is [The Amazons of Somelon by Raymond Kaminski](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?7603).

[image: The Amazons of Somelon]

This kind of matches your description, but only if you've misremembered some elements of the book. The Amazon lady is Sheryl and the queen is Allukah, though Allukah is not a troll - she is the queen of a barbarian horde called the Horlas.

The Amazon Sheryl does indeed get a bash on the head. She is knocked unconscious when barbarians called Horlas attack the caravan she is guarding. But I can't find any reference to a talking Sun and Sheryl doesn't turn into a troll.

The chap who is castrated is Kio though he isn't exactly castrated just, erm, left rather mauled by Allukah's attentions:

> As Kio shuffled along, the aching orbs between his legs slapped from one thigh to the next, swinging like pendulums. The entire foreskin was gone from his penis, shredded by Allukah's coarse hair, coarsened by her two sets of chapped lips, and gnawed by her crooked teeth.

The part with the dead father's corpse is when Kio finds the mummy of Allukah's father, though the penis isn't used for any rituals:

> Kio found her father's body in a small room lined with stalls and white porcelain bowls, exactly where Allukah had hidden it. Lugging the stiff corpse ripe with embalming fluid all the way out to the light, he scooped a hole in a soft heap of rubble with his bare hands and placed the dead man inside. Kio was particularly careful to bring the mummy's severed penis along too. He knew what it felt like to be half a man, even if he didn't know what it felt like to be dead.

Comment: Yeah that was the book with the talking sun. The Cover was a bit different perhaps theres another version with a less edited book. I remember the talking sun I thought the publisher had a B in it like some mythical monster.

Comment: With your excerpts seem unfamilar. Kio was like caged but under control of another munik or something. And I thought it was the main characters mother with the corpse and penis.

Comment: Yeah That is simiilar to the cover I wonder if the UK version was different than the US version.

Comment: I was around the time I read the General who zapped an Angel thats a collection of shorts.

Comment: Zero matches Side note: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=the+general+who+zapped+an+angel&type=Name

Comment: @openInvent [Is this the book](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?875492). I used the advanced search and searched for all books with *general* and *angel* in the title.